# how do I read application.properties data jdbc sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

There is a SQLiteConnection class, there is an application.properties property file with two values :
db.url="jdbc:sqlite:db//untitled.db"
db.driver="org.sqlite.JDBC"

how do I transfer them to the driver and the path to the database, I need it to keep the text in the properties, and not open, so that the text is closed

add sqlite jar

[image]

sqlite driver

[image]

application.properties property

[image]

class SQLiteConnection

```
        import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.Driver;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    
    
    public class SQLiteConnection {
    
        private static Connection con;
        private static String URL_KEY = "db.url";
        private static String DRIVER_DB = "db.driver";
    
        public static Connection getConnection() throws IOException {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            try (var inputStream = PropertiesUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties")) {
                properties.load(inputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
    
            System.out.println("empty??" + properties.isEmpty()); // false
            System.out.println("size ???" + properties.size()); // 2
            System.out.println("get " + properties.get(URL_KEY)); //"jdbc:sqlite:db//untitled.db"
    
            try {
       
               // Driver driver = (Driver) Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(); // work
Driver driver = (Driver) Class.forName(properties.getProperty(DRIVER_DB)).getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(); // not worked
               // String url = "jdbc:sqlite:db" + File.separator + "untitled.db"; //work
                String url = properties.getProperty(URL_KEY); // not worked
                try {
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                    if (con == null) {
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                    }
                    return con;
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    return null;
                }
    
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SQLiteConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
    
            return null;
        }
    }
```

2 error:

```
    2022 5:24:46 PM db.SQLiteConnection getConnection
SEVERE: null
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "org.sqlite.JDBC"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at db.SQLiteConnection.getConnection(SQLiteConnection.java:41)
    at storage.DbStorage.findAll(DbStorage.java:45)
    at storage.DbStorage.<init>(DbStorage.java:35)
    at entity.impls.TodoActionsImpl.<clinit>(TodoActionsImpl.java:59)
    at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:15)

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at storage.DbStorage.findAll(DbStorage.java:46)
    at storage.DbStorage.<init>(DbStorage.java:35)
    at entity.impls.TodoActionsImpl.<clinit>(TodoActionsImpl.java:59)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: properties file is loaded correctly; jvm couldn't find `org.sqlite.JDBC` in your classpath, if you're using sqlite-jdbc, its jar file should be available in your classpath

Comment: Ok, update post, 2 photo sqlite jar path and module add